# How can we use the same Resource with different filters?

Tags: admin-on-rest

I have this Resource:

```
<Resource
      options={{label: 'Assets'}}
      name="assets"
      list={AssetList}
      show={AssetShow}
      edit={AssetEdit}
      create={AssetCreate}
      remove={Delete}
      icon={AssetsIcon}
/>
```

And I need to show exactly the same resource but **filtered** by one of its fields (i.e. `type === 'printer'` by default, filter being hidden), so that we create a "Printers" CRUD for the Assets:

```
<Resource
    options={{label: 'Assets - Printers'}}
    name="assets"
    list={AssetList}
    show={AssetShow}
    edit={AssetEdit}
    create={AssetCreate}
    remove={Delete}
    icon={AssetsIcon}
/>
```

How can we send a "custom" parameter to the Resource and use this for fetching the resource data with a filter? (and also filter the "create", etc)?